# arangoimp, how do I specify database name?

Tags: arangodb

I started to pour in data using arangoimp.exe. It seems to load into _system.

How do I specify database name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the option `--server.database <dbname>`, where `<dbname>` is the name of the database to import into. More options are listed on [the manual page](https://docs.arangodb.com/Arangoimp/index.html).

Should you be unclear about a command's option, you can also use the `--help` argument, e.g. `arangoimp.exe --help` This will list the command's options.